# How do I set the Cluster font attributes in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

I am able to successfully change the edge font, and the node font, but my attempts to change the cluster labels have no affect. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I have tried `labelfontname=`, `fontname=` (on the edge and the node), but can't seem to find the magic formula for cluster labels.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fontname` is working for cluster labels.

Here's an example with illustration - it's quite simple, just set it before setting the content of the label.

```
digraph g{
  node[fontname="Impact"];
  subgraph cluster0 {
    "Cluster node";
    fontname="Courier";
    label="Cluster label";
  }
  fontname="Arial";
  label="Graph Label";
}
```

The result:

[image: graphviz output showing the effect of fontname on a cluster]

Comment: Then what font did the node inherit? Just the default Times-Roman?

Comment: Yes - if you'd like to change the font of all nodes, just add `node[fontname="Impact"];` at the beginning (I'll update the example)

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had tried that version, but I must have made too many changes and lost track of what I had tried when. Of course my code is no where near this simple, as it is generated from PHP and Oracle, but I can apply this. Really appreciate it.